# C++ doesn't convert the uppercase "I" character to lowercase correctly

Tags: c++, character-encoding

I have this simple C++ code that converts uppercase characters to lowercase:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cwctype>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::wstring input_str = L"İiIı";
    std::locale loc("tr_TR.UTF-8");
    std::wofstream output_file("lowercase_turkish.txt");
    output_file.imbue(loc);

    for (wchar_t& c : input_str) {
        c = std::towlower(c);
    }

    output_file << input_str << std::endl;
    output_file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

When giving the input `İiIı` I expect the output to be `iiıı` but rather I get the incorrect output `İiiı`

Why is that happening? and how can I solve the problem with minimum changes to the code considering that I use this code to convert uppercase letters to lowercase in **more than 10 languages** and it works well on all of them except Turkish.

I don't prefer a solution that is very specific to Turkish.

Comment: `std::towlower` uses current C locale. Try `std::tolower(c, loc)` instead.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik unfortunately it still gives me the same output, `İiiı`, I wonder if the output is compiler-dependent

Comment: `ıiiı`? Are you sure? Not `iiıı`?

Comment: "it still gives me the same output" This is rather strange. What compiler and OS are you using?

Comment: @n.m. I tested your solution on linux using GCC C++11 and it worked! but on windows 11, VS 2022 community v17.4.3 it didn't work

Comment: File a bug to Microsoft.

Comment: You can also try ICU or possibly [Boost.Locale](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html) on top of ICU, which you probably should be doing anyway if you are serious about text manipulation. I don't have much experience with it but from what I hear, it just works. Note ICU is rather heavy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

References from Wikipedia

[Dotless I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotless_I) = **I**, ı / **U+0049**, U+0131 / **LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I**,    LATIN SMALL LETTER
DOTLESS I

[Dotted İ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%B0) = **İ**, i / **U+0130**, U+0069 / **LATIN CAPITAL LETTER
I WITH DOT ABOVE**, LATIN SMALL LETTER I

[Latin I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I) = **I**, i / **U+0049(LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I)**, U+0069(LATIN SMALL LETTER I)

[Latin alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet) largely unaltered with the exception of extensions (such as diacritics), it is used to write English and other modern European languages.

Check [Dotted and dotless I in computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I_in_computing)

"İiIı" tolower using latin locale is "iiiı", any upper I,İ is lowered to i

"İiIı" tolower using turkish locale is "iiıı", İ is lowered to i and I is lowered to ı

---

**Test Code - C++**

using [ICU](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/tag/release-72-1) on Windows

The code was compiled with Microsoft Visual C++ compiler.

To use this code

1. Install PowerShell 7.x
2. Run the script "**Compile.ps1**". It downloads ICU Lib and compile the code.
3. Run the script "**Run.ps1**". It runs the generated program in dist folder.

You can clone/test/run the full source code from https://github.com/JomaStackOverflowAnswers/ToLowerTurkish

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unicode/unistr.h>
#include <unicode/ustream.h>
#include <unicode/locid.h>
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#endif


using namespace std::string_literals;
int main()
{
    using namespace icu;
    #ifdef _WIN32
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    #endif

    std::u16string data = u"İstanbul, Diyarbakır, DİYARBAKIR, Türkiye  İiIı  \u0130\u0069\u0049\u0131 - Default locale = "s;
    std::string data2 =  u8"İstanbul, Diyarbakır, DİYARBAKIR, Türkiye  İiIı  \u0130\u0069\u0049\u0131 - Custom Locale  = "s;
    
    UnicodeString localeName;

    UnicodeString uni_str(data.c_str(), data.length());
    uni_str.toLower();
    uni_str += Locale::getDefault().getDisplayName(localeName);

    UnicodeString uni_str2 = UnicodeString::fromUTF8(StringPiece(data2));
    Locale turkishLocale("tr", "TR");
    uni_str2.toLower(turkishLocale);
    uni_str2 += turkishLocale.getDisplayName(localeName);
    

    std::string str;
    uni_str.toUTF8String(str);

    std::string str2;
    uni_str2.toUTF8String(str2);

    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    std::cout << str2 << std::endl;
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;//0
}
```

**Output**

```
i̇stanbul, diyarbakır, di̇yarbakir, türkiye  i̇iiı  i̇iiı - default locale = English (United States)
istanbul, diyarbakır, diyarbakır, türkiye  iiıı  iiıı - custom locale  = Turkish (Turkey)
```

**Screenshots C++ CODE**

**Visual Studio Code**

[image: vscode]

**Windows Terminal**

[image: wt]

---

**Test Code - C#**

You can test/check from https://replit.com/@JomaCorpFX/ToLowerTurkish#main.cs

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    string data = "İstanbul, Diyarbakır, DİYARBAKIR, Türkiye  İiIı  \u0130\u0069\u0049\u0131";
        CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        Console.WriteLine($"System Culture {culture.Name}");
        Console.WriteLine(data.ToLower(culture));

        CultureInfo turkishCulture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
    Console.WriteLine($"Custom Culture {turkishCulture.Name}");
        Console.WriteLine(data.ToLower(turkishCulture));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
System Culture en-US
istanbul, diyarbakır, diyarbakir, türkiye  iiiı  iiiı
Custom Culture tr-TR
istanbul, diyarbakır, diyarbakır, türkiye  iiıı  iiıı
```

---

**Test Code - Java**

You can test/check from https://replit.com/@JomaCorpFX/ToLowerTurkish-1#Main.java

```
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "İstanbul, Diyarbakır, DİYARBAKIR, Türkiye  İiIı  \u0130\u0069\u0049\u0131";
    Locale current = Locale.getDefault();
    System.out.println("Current Locale: " + current);
    System.out.println(data.toLowerCase(current));

    Locale turkishLocale = new Locale("tr", "TR");
    System.out.println("Custom Locale: " + turkishLocale);
    System.out.println(data.toLowerCase(turkishLocale));
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
Current Locale: en_US
i̇stanbul, diyarbakır, di̇yarbakir, türkiye  i̇iiı  i̇iiı
Custom Locale: tr_TR
istanbul, diyarbakır, diyarbakır, türkiye  iiıı  iiıı
```

---

**Test Code - Python ❌**

WARNING. On Windows locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "tr_TR.UTF-8") can't change the locale it remains the same.

```
import locale

data = "İstanbul, Diyarbakır, DİYARBAKIR, Türkiye  İiIı  \u0130\u0069\u0049\u0131"
defaultLocale = locale.getdefaultlocale()
print("Default Locale: " + str(defaultLocale))
print(data.lower())

turkishlocale = locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "tr_TR.UTF-8")
print("Custom Locale: " + str(turkishlocale))
print(data.lower())
```

**Output**

```
PS C:\Users\Megam\Downloads\icu4c-72_1-data-bin-b\TestIcu\ToLowerTurkish> python
Python 3.9.13 (tags/v3.9.13:6de2ca5, May 17 2022, 16:36:42) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import locale
>>>
>>> data = "İstanbul, Diyarbakır, DİYARBAKIR, Türkiye �� İiIı �� \u0130\u0069\u0049\u0131"
>>> defaultLocale = locale.getdefaultlocale()
>>> print("Default Locale: " + str(defaultLocale))
Default Locale: ('en_US', 'cp1252')
>>> print(data.lower())
i̇stanbul, diyarbakır, di̇yarbakir, türkiye  i̇iiı  i̇iiı
>>>
>>> turkishlocale = locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "tr_TR.UTF-8")
>>> print("Custom Locale: " + str(turkishlocale))
Custom Locale: tr_TR.UTF-8
>>> print(data.lower())
i̇stanbul, diyarbakır, di̇yarbakir, türkiye  i̇iiı  i̇iiı
>>>
```

Answer (score 7):

You apply the locale in `std::wcout` for printing, but not during the conversion to lowercase. `std::towlower` (which is a C function) uses the C locale.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/towlower

To fix this, do:

```cpp
for (auto& c : input_str)
    c = std::tolower<wchar_t>(c, loc); // defined in <locale>
```

*However*, the output would be:

```
iiiı
```

even though it should be `iiıı`.

The reason for this seems to be that, as you can see [here](https://unicode-table.com/en/alphabets/turkish/), turkish uses the regular latin `I` but the turkish-specific `ı`, and so the conversion of `I` to lowercase is wrong (regular ascii characters can be mixed with turkish unicode ones).

So you should use a turkish-specific solution:

```cpp
for (auto& c : input_str)
    c = c == L'I' ? L'ı' : std::tolower<wchar_t>(c, loc);
```

Comment: I like this answer better than mine, because this one is "surgical" and just targets the specific `tolower`, whereas my `std::setlocale` is global and affects everything.

Comment: "the output would be:" It works for me just fine and outputs `iiıı` as expected.

Comment: Oh? I tried it and got `iiiı`. And OP commented that they got `İiiı`. I guess different implementations handle it differently.

Comment: What compiler and OS?

Comment: macOS with Apple clang

Comment: `İiiı` is an evidence that Unicode beyond ASCII is not being processed at all (which is expected, given that OP is calling a wrong function). `iiıı` is an evidence that Unicode is being processed according to the generic algorithm rather than locale-specific algorithm. So the Turkish locale on a Mac is broken in this respect. I am on Linux and it works just fine there (and I also see in the locale source that Turkish case conventions are respected).

Comment: The problem is with the first character `İ`, your solution never have impact on this char, it always stays the same after lowercase

Comment: @user2401856 What is your platform? The turkish locale in your machine is buggy, just like in my case. You should manually check for those `i`s to compensate.

Comment: Also the problem is not just the first character, your expected output should be `iiıı`

Comment: @guard3 I'm using windows 11, VS 2022 community v17.4.3

Answer (score 5):

You need to have the Turkish locale used for `std::towlower`.  Otherwise its using the **C** locale, which is rather ASCII-centric.

```
#include <clocale>
#include <cwctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::wstring input_str = L"İiIıÇç";
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "tr_TR.UTF-8"); // This should impact std::towlower
    std::locale loc("tr_TR.UTF-8");
    std::wofstream output_file("lowercase_turkish.txt");
    output_file.imbue(loc);

    for (wchar_t& c : input_str) {
        c = std::towlower(c);
    }

    output_file << input_str << std::endl;
    output_file.close();
}
```

Comment: it still gives me `İiiıçç` :(

Comment: The problem is with the first character `İ`, your solution never have impact on this char, it always stays the same after lowercase

Comment: I tried it on my Mac, and I'm getting `iiiıçç` — which is still wrong on the 3 character.  On Linux, I'm getting `iiııçç`.  Seems like a bug in macOS, at least on my Mac.  The streams & locales & Unicode handling is (in my opinion) not very robust.  I've had better luck with [ICU](https://icu.unicode.org/design/cpp) with C++, but I've not had to use ICU with Turkish localization.  I have fixed bugs with SQL and Turkish localization — the user locale should not be used to interpret the SQL statements (they should be in C locale... but they're not).